# Does maximum likelihood minimize a kind of generalized "0-1 loss"?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, decision-theory, loss-functions

A very good point was raised [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/143712/36229) about how the optimal betting strategy under 0-1 loss was to bet on the mode, while under MSE loss the optimal strategy was to bet on the mean.

Maximum likelihood is, in many cases, equivalent to a posterior mode. Does the "all-or-nothing loss function" analogy extend to more general cases? Is MLE sub-optimal, in a decision-theoretic sense, for statistical inference, as compared to something like least squares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "does 0-1 loss function analogy extend to more general cases?"

As you noted, depending on your loss function, you can find a different point estimate that maximizes your posterior.  For e.g., if you care about least-squares error, you would pick the posterior distribution's mean.  For absolute value loss, you pick the median.  Here is a doc that outlines proofs for all these http://www.cogsci.ucsd.edu/~ajyu/Teaching/Tutorials/bayes_dt.pdf.

However, note that the full information for decision making is contained in the distribution in the spirit of true Bayesian thinking.